# Does integrating over different curves give different results?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, definite-integrals

When we're integrating a one variable function, there is only one path to follow between points $a$ and $b$.

$F(b)=F(a)+h(f(a)+f(a+h)+f(a+2h)+........)$ where $h$ is very small. So, we approach from $a$ to $b$ in steps of $h$ along the line joining unique path joining $a$ and $b$.

I was wondering what if we have a multi-variable function $f(x,y)$. What does it mean to integrate $f(x,y)$ from $(a,b)$ to $(c,d)$? Clearly, there isn't a unique path joining $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$.

We have partial integration:

$$\int_{(a,b)}^{(c,d)} f(x,y)dxdy=\int_{a}^{c}f(x,b)dx+\int_{b}^{d}f(c,y)dy$$

But that's basically doing it in two steps, first keeping $y$ constant then $x$ constant. How can we vary both $x$ and $y$ simultaneously?

I thought of finding a curve which contains both the points $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ and varying both variables simultaneously along that path. Suppose $g(x)$ is a curve such that $g(a)=b$ and $g(c)=d$. Then we can replace $y$ with $g(x)$ to get:

$$\int_{(a,b)}^{(c,d)} f(x,y)dxdy=\int_a^b f(x,g(x))g'(x)dx$$

Does this integration of $f(x,y)$ from $(a,b)$ to $(c,d)$ depend on the choice of curve $g(x)$?

Comment: You're talking about line integrals, which are indeed path-dependent. See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generically, yes. The integral of $f$ along a path depends on the choice of the path.

For perhaps the simplest example, suppose $f(x,y) \equiv 1$, and choose a path $\gamma(t)$. When I say choose a path $\gamma(t)$, I think of $t$ as indicating 'time' and $\gamma(t)$ as indicating the location of a particle at time $t$, or something. So $\gamma: [a,b] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$.

Then $\int_\gamma 1 dt$ is really another name for the length of the path, and this clearly depends on the path.

For more, you should look up 'line integrals', which should be covered early in a multivariable calculus text (or in various places online).

Answer (score 0):

Only for some special functions the path-integral is path independent.

In general it gives different results.

Take a look here:

[What does it mean for an integral to be independent of a path?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1734106/what-does-it-mean-for-an-integral-to-be-independent-of-a-path)